# Rails 4 TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to make a system for blocking users.

I'm trying to select battles that the user didn't block their owner

What i tried so far is :

```
blocked_user_list = BlockedUser.where(:blocker_user_id => user.id).pluck(:user_id) 

  # If the user blocked any users
  if (blocked_user_list.length > 0)
    battles = Battle.all.join(:users).where("battles.user_id NOT IN (?)", blocked_user_list)
  end
```

The structe of the tables

```
create_table "blocked_users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id" # The id of the blocked user
  t.integer  "blocker_user_id" # The id of the blocker user
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
end

create_table "battles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "title"
  t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
end
```

The error im getting is : Rails 4 TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String

Comment: Please provide your error trace

Comment: 2016-06-04T11:54:57.718154+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):

Comment: Can you post full stack trace? But I can see in your SQL query `battles.user.id NOT IN (?)` should be `battles.user_id NOT IN (?)`

Comment: Thanks, i success to solve the problem affter i saw your answer. there was another error that i wrote down join instead of joins